# Add product programmatically to cart through observer

Tags: cart, event-observer, quote

Here is my questions: What is the right event to hook in for adding a product to quote programmatically (entry sales_flat_quote_item table). Also i have to catch the items/products added to cart from an user/customer, because their data informations will determine the product which will be added programmatically. So the scenario would be:

1. user/customer adds a product to cart
2. find the right event for hook in
3. fetch informations about the products added to cart
4. add additional product to cart based on a product id and modified its data

In my opinion its better to work with the quote, before the products are written to the database.

I figure out how to add it through **Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::_addCatalogProduct()**. But i would like to do it through an event observer instead of overwriting core classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

these are observer maches with your requirement.

```
sales_quote_add_item
sales_quote_product_add_after
checkout_cart_product_add_after
checkout_cart_add_product_complete
checkout_cart_update_item_complete
checkout_cart_update_items_before
checkout_cart_update_items_after
checkout_cart_save_before
checkout_cart_save_after
checkout_cart_product_update_after
sales_quote_product_add_after
```

Refer these links for events in magento

1. http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-7/
2. http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/events